# possible to move out of field and then overwrite enum in safe rust?

Tags: rust

I have a function, which takes an enum with two variants and converts it to a particular variant. I can only get it to compile with unsafe `ptr::{read,write}`, but it feels like it should be possible to do in safe code - I'm unconditionally assigning to `*self`, so it should be find to consume (parts of) the current value.

Is there a way to write this function in safe Rust?

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*x` which is behind a mutable reference
 --> src/lib.rs:9:29
  |
9 |             *self = Self::B(*x);
  |                             ^^ move occurs because `*x` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

```
enum Foo<T> {
    A(T),
    B(T),
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn ensure_b(&mut self) {
        if let Self::A(x) = self {
            *self = Self::B(*x);
        }
    }

    unsafe fn ensure_b_unsafe(&mut self) {
        if let Self::A(x) = self {
            let new_self = Self::B(core::ptr::read(x));
            core::ptr::write(self, new_self);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f60b8d3d1188a3357fb6f7477aa8c26)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question, which is 8 years old, with an answer that is three years old and requires unsafe, which is entirely unneeded here

Comment: @user2722968 This answer mentions crates that encapsulate this unsafe code, and another answer mentions `std::mem::replace()`. Old questions and answers are not automatically invalid. If there are new answers since then, you can answer there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't move `T` of `&mut self` "temporarily" - what if the code that follows panics, before moving a value back in? That's why it is not possible in safe Rust in the way you described.

The solution is to put a value into self that acts as a temporary value, so `&mut self` stays in a well-defined state, while taking ownership of the contained `T`. This is easily possible if `T: Copy`, if `T: Default`, or if `Foo` has a cheap variant independent of `T`.

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Foo<T> {
    A(T),
    B(T),
}

impl<T: Default> Foo<T> {
    fn ensure_b(&mut self) {
        // Use `std::mem::replace` to take ownership of self, putting a default
        // in its place. Then construct a new owned value (which is always of
        // the B-variant, and assign it to `self`. This is always safe, even
        // if we panic while constructing the new value for `self`.
        *self = match std::mem::replace(self, Foo::A(Default::default())) {
            Foo::A(t) | Foo::B(t) => Foo::B(t),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Foo::A("foo");
    f.ensure_b();
    assert_eq!(f, Foo::B("foo"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest an alternative to user2722968's answer. If `Foo::A` and `Foo::B` are structurally the same but just need to be distinguished by their tag, perhaps the tag should be a separate enum entirely.

```
struct Foo {
  foo_type: FooType,
  inner: T
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum FooType {
  A,
  B,
}
```

Now there's no need to move anything out. We just update the tag and do whatever other internal logic needs doing.

```
fn ensure_b(&mut self) {
  if self.foo_type == FooType::A {
    self.foo_type = FooType::B;
    // Do whatever needs to be done to self.inner to "update".
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A third option is to modify `Foo<T>` to take into account the intermediate state between the moment you take the inner value and the moment you put it in again.

```rust
enum Foo<T> {
    A(T),
    B(T),
    Poisoned,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn ensure_b(&mut self) {
        *self = match std::mem::replace(self, Self::Poisoned) {
            Self::A(x) | Self::B(x) => Self::B(x),
            Self::Poisoned => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, on a small example like this, it can be quite inconvenient to have an extra variant because you have to consider the poisoned case everywhere else. However, if you are in a larger codebase, it can be very hard to ensure that nothing happens between the moment you take the value and the moment you put it back again (especially if you use `unsafe` Rust), especially because of [exception safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exception-safety.html). If you force everyone to handle the case where something went wrong, suddenly you don't have to ensure anymore that everything went fine, which is a design choice that is less likely to create bugs in the future.

This kind of design is used in practice, especially in concurrent data structures where reasoning about what should and should not happen between two consecutive instructions is particularly hard. See [poisoning](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/poisoning.html).